# SQL SUM function without grouping data

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I need to do a sum of a variable broken by certain other variables. I normally would do this with the `group by` function.

However in this case, I do not want to roll-up the data. I want to keep the original data with some sort of aggregated `sum`.

```
-ID-- --amount--
  1        23
  1        11
  1        8
  1        7
  2        10
  2        20
  2        15
  2        10
```

Result

```
-ID-- --amount-----SUM
  1        23      49
  1        11      49
  1        8       49
  1        7       49
  2        10      55
  2        20      55
  2        15      55
  2        10      55
```

Comment: `group by` in a derived table, then `JOIN` to the original table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a subquery to get the total for each `id` and join that back to your table:

```
select t.id, 
  t.amount, 
  t1.total
from yt t
inner join 
(
  select id, sum(amount) total
  from yt
  group by id
) t1
  on t.id = t1.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9e15/4)

Comment: This is the best you can do, since MySQL doesn't have analytical functions.