# Unknown column on subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Built a sub-query, but getting an unknown column in on clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM FINAL_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE_AllCOUNTS
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT COUNT(FINAL_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE_AllCOUNTS.Phy_PLN_CD), SUM(FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE.X12_Cost_High), 
Total_Low-SUM(FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE.X12_Cost_Low),
Total_High-SUM(FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE.X12_Cost_High),  
AVG_WITHIN_Fac-SUM(FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE.X12_Cost_Ave) FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE 
FROM FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE, FINAL_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE_AllCOUNTS
GROUP BY FINAL_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE_AllCOUNTS.TC_Code, FINAL_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE_AllCOUNTS.Phy_PROV_NO
) a ON
FINAL_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE_AllCOUNTS.Phy_PROV_NO=FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE.Phy_PROV_NO
AND FINAL_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE_AllCOUNTS.TC_Code=FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE.TC_Code;
```

Getting error- Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE.Phy_PROV_NO' in 'on clause'. I have changed it to a.Phy_PROV_NO', but get the same error.

Comment: `Phy_PROV_NO` isn't a column in your sub-select, so it cannot be used to JOIN with.  Also, using aliases for your tables would make this easier to read.

Comment: THanks- will work on the alias. Tried a quick fix of just putting at Select *, .... in the sub- but then get a duplicate column error.

Comment: Your `SELECT *` brings all columns from both tables in your FROM - Both tables have at least one column in common.  Also, it is better practice to use proper JOIN syntax instead of the older `FROM table,table2` that you currently have.

Comment: The subquery doesn't have a join condition, do you really want a full cross-product between the two tables?

Comment: I think I do- here was my original question that got me to build the subquery to begin with. I gave a little more simple example than reality. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846605/sql-sum-function-without-grouping-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is what you actually want:

```
SELECT allc.TC_Code, allc.Phy_PROV_NO,
       COUNT(allc.Phy_PLN_CD), SUM(bcare.X12_Cost_High), 
       Total_Low-SUM(bcare.X12_Cost_Low),
       Total_High-SUM(bcare.X12_Cost_High),  
       AVG_WITHIN_Fac-SUM(bcare.X12_Cost_Ave) 
FROM FINAL_MOP_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE bcare
JOIN FINAL_Professional_SP_2013_BCARE_AllCOUNTS allc
ON allc.Phy_PROV_NO = bcare.Phy_PROV_NO AND allc.TC_Code = bcare.TC_Code
GROUP BY allc.TC_Code, allc.Phy_PROV_NO
```

You had your join condition for the subquery outside the subquery.